# NGINX allow access only to specific URLs (whitelist)

Tags: nginx

I would like to allow access only to specific URLs (whitelist) in NGINX configuration but deny to others URLs. For example:

allow only access to: https://domain.com/name/?cmp=DefaultDashboard

Can you help and give some idea how to do that please? Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    ...

    set $access_denied 1;

    if ($request_uri = /name/?cmp=DefaultDashboard) {
        set $access_denied 0;
    }

    if ($access_denied) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

Note that this is using an exact match on the request URI and the order of the request parameters is important.